# Temporarily store audio file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm currently building a web application that requires a fairly large audio file (~50mb) to be accessible offline.

I attempted this with fetching a base64 string of the audio file from the web server, then modifying the DOM by adding an audio element that points to the base64 string with using data:. However, this does not work in Chrome for Android; due to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253466).

I'm wondering if there's a better solution to the problem that works on Chrome for Android.

Thanks in advance.